# Delete last table row added programmatically to a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, razor

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web Api 2.2 app with .NET Framework 4.5, C# and jQuery.

I have this table on a view:

```
<table id ="batchTable" class="order-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h4>Product</h4>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <h4>Codes</span></h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h4>Label1</h4>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h4>Label2</h4>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h4>Label3</h4>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h4>Label4</h4>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h4>Label5</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="group">
                  <input type="text" 
                      name="BatchProducts[0].BatchName" 
                      id="BatchProducts[0].BatchName"
                      required />
                  @*<span class="highlight"></span>
                  <span class="bar"></span>
                  <label>Name</label>*@
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="group">
                  <input type="text" 
                      name="BatchProducts[0].BatchPO" 
                      id="BatchProducts[0].BatchPO"
                      required />
                  @*<span class="highlight"></span>
                  <span class="bar"></span>
                  <label>PO</label>*@
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="group">      
                  <input type="text" class="datepicker"
                      name="BatchProducts[0].MadeDate" 
                      id="BatchProducts[0].MadeDate"
                      required />
                  @*<span class="highlight"></span>
                  <span class="bar"></span>
                  <label>Made</label>*@
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="group">      
                  <input type="text" class="monthPicker"
                      name="BatchProducts[0].ValidateDate" 
                      id="BatchProducts[0].ValidateDate"
                      required />
                  @*<span class="highlight"></span>
                  <span class="bar"></span>
                  <label>Validate</label>*@
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="group">      
                  <input type="text" class="quantity"
                      name="BatchProducts[0].Quantity" 
                      id="BatchProducts[0].Quantity"
                      onkeydown='return (window.event.keyCode >= 48 && window.event.keyCode <= 57) || window.event.keyCode == 8 || window.event.keyCode == 46'
                      required />
                  @*<span class="highlight"></span>
                  <span class="bar"></span>
                  <label>Quantity</label>*@
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: left;">
                            <input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="ibtnDel"  value="Delete last row">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

I use jQuery to add new rows dynamically when user clicks on `addRow` button, and users can also delete the last one row when they click on button `ibtnDel`.

I having problems with delete button. This is its javascript:

```
$("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
    $('table.order-list').each(function () {
        if ($('table.order-list > tbody > tr', this).length > 0) {
            $('table.order-list tbody tr:last', this).remove();
        } else {
            $('tr:last', this).remove();
        }
    });

    counter -= 1
    $('#addrow').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "Add");
});
```

But it doesn't work because `if ($('table.order-list > tbody > tr', this).length > 0)` always return 0. This code delete the `tr` where the buttons `Add` and `Delete last row` are.

This code:

```
if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
    $('tbody tr:last', this).remove();
```

Have worked when the two buttons `Add` and `Delete last row` weren't inside in an inner table.

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="ibtnDel"  value="Delete last row">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

How can I make it work?

JSFidle: https://jsfiddle.net/VansFannel/fa0z225s/12/ This is my first JSFidle and it doesn't work. I don't know if you can edit it.

Comment: Can you please provide a simple _sample_ of your code on [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I fail to see how the ASP.NET parts are relevant for the jQuery question?

Comment: I have added the JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/VansFannel/fa0z225s/5/, but it doesn't work because this is my first JSFiddle and I don't know how to make it work. @Anders, this is an ASP.NET app and I have added as much details as possible.

Comment: Thanks! To include jQuery you need to click the "Javascript" in the top right corner of that box, and choose it from the "Extenstions" drop down. Here is a updated link: https://jsfiddle.net/fa0z225s/6/

Comment: As for the ASP I think the goal is not to include as much detail as possible, but to include only the relevant, but I absolutely see your point. [MCVE]

Comment: @Anders I'm sorry but I made a mistake with the example I have uploaded to JSFiddle. The HTML is wrong, the right example is https://jsfiddle.net/VansFannel/fa0z225s/12/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this......

```
$("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
    if ($('table.order-list > tbody > tr') {
        $('table.order-list > tbody >tr:last-child').remove();
    } 
counter -= 1
$('#addrow').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "Add");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the `this` in `$('table.order-list > tbody > tr', this)` is the context to look within. so `this` in `$('table.order-list').each(function () {` is the table, where you are trying to look for `table.order-list` inside itself ->

```
$("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
   $('table.order-list').each(function () {
      // 'this' is now a table element with the class 'order-list'
      if ($('table.order-list > tbody > tr', this).length > 0) {
      // here you are looking for table.order-list inside 'this' which
      // is already that element.
```

so, you could change this to:-

```
$("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
    if ($('table.order-list > tbody > tr').length > 0) {
        $('table.order-list > tbody > tr:last').remove();
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/fa0z225s/13/)

or if you have multiple tables:-

```
$("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
    var table = $(this).closest('table');
    if ($('tbody > tr', table).length > 0) {
        $('tbody > tr:last', table).remove();
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/fa0z225s/14/)

**UPDATE**

If you are using a table within a table, then you need to be more specific with your selector. One way to do that is using `>`, which means direct/immediate  child:-

```
$("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(event) {
  if ($('table.order-list > tbody > tr').length > 0) {
      $('table.order-list > tbody > tr:last').remove();
  }

  counter -= 1
  $('#addrow').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "Añadir otro lote");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/fa0z225s/15/)

Comment: I have tested your first option and it doesn't work. I have updated my question with a JSFddle but I can't make it work because it is the first time I create one.

Comment: I'm sorry but I made a mistake with the example I have uploaded to JSFiddle. The HTML is wrong, the right example is https://jsfiddle.net/VansFannel/fa0z225s/12/

Answer (score 0):

In your code, this line `$('table.order-list > tbody > tr', this).length` finds the elements of `tr` inside `tbody` having parent `table.order-list` inside `this` element, means you are finding elements inside the table only. so just change the code as

`$('tbody > tr', this).length`

AND

`$('tbody tr:last', this).remove()`

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one, this might help you keep your button row on last position

```
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Table Header</th>
      <th>Table Header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Table cell 1</td>
      <td>Table cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Table cell 3</td>
      <td>Table cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button" class="ibtnAdd">Add Row</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="ibtnDel">Remove Row</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<script>
$("table#myTable").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
    var table = $(this).closest('table');
    var rowLen = $(table).find('tr').length-2;
    $('tbody > tr').eq($(table).find('tr').length-2).remove();
});
</script>
```

**DEMO** [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ShirishDhotre/ztt8z1d9/)